# GitLab setting the CI_JOB_ID as the job's tag

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set the tag of a job to that job's unique ID:

```yaml
some-cool-job:
  tags:
    - $CI_JOB_ID
```

however it doesn't seem to resolve the variable. It just sets the tag to `"$CI_JOB_ID"`. Similarly, `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` doesn't work.

Using `$CI_JOB_NAME` or `$CI_PIPELINE_IID` instead, works fine.
Hence I assume that the ID just doesn't exist at the time the tags are parsed.
Following this, how else can I uniquely identify a job using variables available at this time?

Comment: FYI, using `$CI_JOB_ID` in `some-cool-job.environment.name` leads to the same problem, but with the error message `This job could not be executed because it would create an environment with an invalid parameter`. `$CI_PIPELINE_IID` works here, too.

Answer (score -1):

GitLab assigns a number of [predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for you. One of these is `CI_JOB_ID`. You can view the value by printing it within a script.

```yaml
some-cool-job:
  script:
    - echo $CI_JOB_ID
```

In the context of a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, [tags map jobs to runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags). For instance, I tag my runners with names reflecting the executor being used (e.g. - `shell` or `docker`), then I tag jobs within my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that need a shell executor with `shell`.

May I ask, what is the desired outcome of tagging a job with the job ID, in your case?

Comment: Thank you for regurgitating the documentation. I need them to be unique as I need to dynamically spawn runners for each job and cannot have jobs picked up by runners from different pipelines. The lifetime of the runners must be linked to a pipeline.